# Returning a dictionary with 2 keys from a list of tuples within python

Tags: python, function, tuples

I've got a list of tuples which look like this.

`people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]`

I'm trying to create a function. which has 2 parametres    function(people, name)
The function should return a dictionary with two keys, "age" and "gender", with the values being those from the tuple which contains the name passed as the second argument to the function. If the name isn't found in the list of tuples, return "None."

I'm struggling to create a function as i can't seem to find any information on how to approach a 3 element list of tuples.

any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: Do you want an entry in your dictionary for every possible gender, age pair? For instance the your list doesn’t have anyone who is 33, M. Should this new dictionary also has 33, M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
people1 = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]

def xyz(people, name):
    found={}
    for _name,_age,_gender in people:
        if _name==name:
            found["Age"]=_age
            found["Gender"]=_gender
            return found
    return None
    
print(xyz(people1,"John"))
print(xyz(people1,"John1"))
```

```
{'Age': 36, 'Gender': 'M'}
None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'), ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]

def my_func(people, name:str):
    b = {}
    for person in people:
        if person[0] == name:
            b["Age"] = person[1]
            b["Gender"] = person[2]
    if len(b)>0:
        return b
    else:
        return None
        

c = my_func(people, 'Rachel')
print(c)
d = my_func(people, 'Diana')
print("\n" + str(d))
```

my output:

```
{'Age': 24, 'Gender': 'F'}

None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns list of dictionaries. If there are several tuples with the same name then the function returns all of them inside the list as a dictionaries. If there is not any tuple with the specific name then `None` is returned.

```
def my_f(people, name):
result = []
for each in people:
    if each[0] == name:
        result.append({'age': each[1], 'gender': each[2]})
if len(result) == 0:
    return None
return result
```