# Check if a dictionary value exists by calling the function that creates the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

This is similar to this question (essentially a follow on): [Returning a dictionary with 2 keys from a list of tuples within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955189/returning-a-dictionary-with-2-keys-from-a-list-of-tuples-within-python) but I am trying to write a function which calls the xyz function and finds if someone is a member and returns True or False.

So I've basically borrowed almost verbatim the xyz function:

```
def member_details(persons, name):
    found={}
    for _name,_age,_gender in persons:
        if _name==name:
            found["Age"]=_age
            found["Gender"]=_gender
            return found
    return None
```

and need to write a new function which in turn calls that `member_details` function and finds if someone is a member and returns True or False.

```
def is_member
```

How can I call the `member_details` function from that `is_member` function to do the if - else statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want `is_member` to call `member_details` and if the result is `None` to return `False` and otherwise to return `True`?

Comment: I can imagine that your question received downvotes because it is left unclear why the *obvious* approach wasn't successful. The obvious approach being: (1) "how can I call `member_details`" -> by writing `member_details(x, y)` and providing some arguments `x` and `y`; (2) "returns True or False"/"do the if-else statement" -> by writing `if <some condition>: <do this> else: <do that>` where `<do this>` and `<do that>` somehow involve `return True` and `return False`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 (re: first comment) exactly that if I go by the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple loop.

```
people = [('John', 36, 'M'), ('Rachel', 24, 'F'), ('Deardrie', 78, 'F'),
          ('Ahmed', 17, 'M'), ('Sienna', 14, 'F')]

def is_member(persons, name):
    for x in persons:
        if x[0] == name:
            return True
    return False

is_member(people, 'Rachel')
# True

is_member(people, 'Other')
# False
```

Or a generator with `any`:

```
def is_member(persons, name):
    return any(x[0] == name for x in persons)

is_member(people, 'Rachel')
# True

is_member(people, 'Other')
# False
```

If you plan to call this function frequently (actually probably just more than once or twice), note that this will be much less efficient than using a proper data type from the beginning (such as a dictionary with names as keys):

```
members = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in people}
# {'John': (36, 'M'), 'Rachel': (24, 'F'), 'Deardrie': (78, 'F'),
#  'Ahmed': (17, 'M'), 'Sienna': (14, 'F')}

'Rachel' in members
# True

'Other' in members
# False
```

Comment: Sorry - I think either I'm confused (quite possible!) or being confusing in my question. I need to write a function which calls the member_details function. It's practice assignments for a data science apprenticeship I'm doing, so I have to stay within the directions.

Comment: Create a function called ```is_member``` which takes two arguments:

a list of tuples, in the same format as people above (with the name as the first element in each)
a string, representing a name to be checked whether it is in the list
The function should itself call the ```member_details``` function you defined earlier to determine whether there is a match; ```is_member``` should return ```True``` if there is, and ```False``` otherwise.

Comment: I see. Then a simple `def is_member(people, name): return bool(member_details(people, name))` should work as `member_details` returns None on no-match. With if else: `def is_member(people, name): return False if member_details(people, name) is None else True`, but not very pythonic…

Comment: I think maybe because we're absolute beginners we're just doing stuff that works at all rather than works well.

Is it okay to use 'people' as the first parameter if 'people' is already defining the list of tuples with the names, ages and genders?

Comment: you can use whatever name you want, the scopes are independent. You could use `def is_member(name, people): return bool(member_details(name, people))` if you want to be sneaky (please don't do it), as long as you call `is_member(people, name)` this will work.